# How to use this class in my c# code

Tags: c#, namespaces

How would I be able to use IAxaptaWrapper from this class ?

```
 namespace Axapta
{
    internal class Axapta : IAxaptaWrapper
```

and

```
namespace Axapta
{
    public class AxThreadedWrapper: IAxaptaWrapper
    {
```

My attempt to ref the dll library and then

use it like

```
using (IAxaptaWrapper Ax = new AxThreadedWrapper())

        {
```

The type or namespace name 'AxThreadedWrapper' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Axapta library in your project?

Answer (score 2):

You need a using directive not a using statement. They are different.

A [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) allows you to omit namespace qualifiers in your code. You'll need a using directive for IAxaptaWrapper as well as AxThreadedWrapper. They could very well be in the same namespace.

A [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) effectively wraps a try-finally .Dispose around a block of code. You only use it if the object implements IDisposable.

---

Now you have added `internal` to the class. That means you can't use it in another assembly (in the normal way). The default [access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) for a non-nested class is `internal` so you'll need to replace it with `public` because you want to access it from another assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to Axapta at the top of the class with the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) directive.

```
using Axapta;
using System;
```

Comment: @UserAnonymous you have using _statement_, not using _directive_

Comment: This could be a bit confusing... Do you have both the using directive as I have detailed and the using statement as you have mentioned in your question?

Comment: using (IAxaptaWrapper Ax = new AxThreadedWrapper())
            {

                Ax.Logon("Auto", "", "", "Original (installed configuration)");

Comment: A "reference" is something entirely different. They aren't in source code, they are compiler arguments (normally set in the project.)